# Ncat inside WSL2 not behaving correctly

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux, port, netcat

I have an instance of kali linux running in WSL2 on Windows 11. It is configured to use mirrored networking mode, if that is relevant. Typically, if one were to start listening on 127.0.0.1 on any given port (say 5055) (`nc -nvlp 5055`) and then on the same machine use ncat to connect to that port (`nc 127.0.0.1 5055`), a connection would be made and you would be able to type and send data. Whenever I try this, I instead receive a connection on the listening side (left) and "successfully" do likewise on the sending end (right). But, When I attempt to send the first bit of data the connection dies and the recipient does not receive that data. The first picture is done using netcat `[v1.10-48]`, and the second picture is using nmap's version. Why is this happening? This used to work just fine a couple weeks ago, and nothing has changed.

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Things I've tried:

- Fresh install of kali
- Disable windows firewall
- Flush iptables
- Run as sudo
- Add `-k` flag

Also, there is more strange behavior: I am able to listen on the same port with multiple (in this case, 4) processes without issue. Executing `netstat -tnupl` also shows each individual PID listening independently:
[image]

...but it gets even weirder. When multiple netcats are listening on the same port and I try to connect to that port, it simply goes to the listener which was started most recently. If I then try to create **another** connection to that port while the previous is still active, it goes to the listener started previously to the still-active one. **In this scenario, the behavior of ncat is what it is supposed to be. Data can be send and received without issue, only closing the connection on ^C**
[image]

I've been banging my head against the wall for weeks trying to figure this out. If anyone has experienced this before or has a solution, I would be super appreciative! TIA!

edit: Here are the commands I used:

`nc -nvlp 5055` -> `nc localhost 5055` The expected behavior would be for the connection to stay established and data to be sent from stdin on client side to server side.

edit 2: Here are some strace logs, which may be helpful
`strace nc -nvlp 5055` -> `strace nc 127.0.0.1 5055` (respectively)

```
% strace nc -nvlp 5055                                                                                                                  24-03-14 - 18:55:16
execve("/usr/bin/nc", ["nc", "-nvlp", "5055"], 0x7fff75e4b840 /* 39 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5578d9b11000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f816adda000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=89731, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 89731, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f816adc4000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220x\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1926256, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 1974096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f816abe2000
mmap(0x7f816ac08000, 1396736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f816ac08000
mmap(0x7f816ad5d000, 344064, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17b000) = 0x7f816ad5d000
mmap(0x7f816adb1000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1cf000) = 0x7f816adb1000
mmap(0x7f816adb7000, 53072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f816adb7000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f816abdf000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f816abdf740) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f816abdfa10)         = 6959
set_robust_list(0x7f816abdfa20, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7f816abe0060, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7f816adb1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x5578d9a4f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f816ae0c000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f816adc4000, 89731)           = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=196, ...}, 0) = 0
getrandom("\xe5\xc1\x3b\x27\xa4\x6e\x80\xdd", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5578d9b11000
brk(0x5578d9b32000)                     = 0x5578d9b32000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "multi on\n", 4096)             = 9
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7f816adbe42c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=196, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# This file was automatically ge"..., 4096) = 196
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="Sovngarde-2", ...}) = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=196, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x5578d9a4a2f0, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x5578d9a4a2f0, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x5578d9a4a2f0, sa_mask=[TERM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGURG, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[URG], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 526
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=89731, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 89731, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f816adc4000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=122880, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=122880, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7fff4fa94ab0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
munmap(0x7f816adc4000, 89731)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12813, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "# Network services, Internet sty"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "\ntinc\t\t655/tcp\t\t\t\t# tinc control"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "cd\t6445/tcp\tsge_execd\t# Grid Eng"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "es\namidxtape\t10083/tcp\t\t\t# amand"..., 4096) = 525
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5055), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 1)                            = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5055), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, [16]) = 0
write(2, "listening on [any] 5055 ...", 27listening on [any] 5055 ...) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60960), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 4
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f816ac1e510}, 8) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
getsockopt(4, SOL_IP, IP_OPTIONS, 0x5578d9b12490, [40 => 0]) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5055), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
write(2, "connect to [127.0.0.1] from (UNK"..., 55connect to [127.0.0.1] from (UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 60960) = 55
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
pselect6(5, [0 4], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

```
% strace nc 127.0.0.1 5055                                                                                                              24-03-14 - 18:55:35
execve("/usr/bin/nc", ["nc", "127.0.0.1", "5055"], 0x7ffd5f734b00 /* 39 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559cd1d18000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19a7309000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=89731, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 89731, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19a72f3000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220x\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1926256, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 1974096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19a7111000
mmap(0x7f19a7137000, 1396736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f19a7137000
mmap(0x7f19a728c000, 344064, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17b000) = 0x7f19a728c000
mmap(0x7f19a72e0000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1cf000) = 0x7f19a72e0000
mmap(0x7f19a72e6000, 53072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19a72e6000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19a710e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f19a710e740) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f19a710ea10)         = 7181
set_robust_list(0x7f19a710ea20, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7f19a710f060, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7f19a72e0000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x559cd0dd7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f19a733b000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f19a72f3000, 89731)           = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=196, ...}, 0) = 0
getrandom("\xc7\x34\xec\xd4\xd0\x66\xcb\x26", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559cd1d18000
brk(0x559cd1d39000)                     = 0x559cd1d39000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "multi on\n", 4096)             = 9
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7f19a72ed42c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=196, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# This file was automatically ge"..., 4096) = 196
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="Sovngarde-2", ...}) = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=196, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x559cd0dd22f0, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x559cd0dd22f0, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x559cd0dd22f0, sa_mask=[TERM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGURG, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[URG], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 526
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=89731, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 89731, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19a72f3000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=122880, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=122880, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffee19a18a0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
munmap(0x7f19a72f3000, 89731)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12813, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "# Network services, Internet sty"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "\ntinc\t\t655/tcp\t\t\t\t# tinc control"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "cd\t6445/tcp\tsge_execd\t# Grid Eng"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "es\namidxtape\t10083/tcp\t\t\t# amand"..., 4096) = 525
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12813, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "# Network services, Internet sty"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "\ntinc\t\t655/tcp\t\t\t\t# tinc control"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "cd\t6445/tcp\tsge_execd\t# Grid Eng"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "es\namidxtape\t10083/tcp\t\t\t# amand"..., 4096) = 525
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5055), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f19a714d510}, 8) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
pselect6(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULLabc
) = 1 (in [0])
read(0, "abc\n", 8192)                  = 4
write(3, "abc\n", 4)                    = 4
pselect6(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])
read(3, 0x559cd1d1b710, 8192)           = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: I ran NC inside Kali inside a proper VM (VMware) and it worked fine. WSL is not the best platform for Kali.